# Install Kubuntu(16.04) and GRUB to an external drive to create a portable OS

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, kubuntu

Yesterday I tried to install `Kubuntu 16.04 LTS` onto an 8GB USB2.0 Stick following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/170456/228612) answer. I changed the location for the bootloader to install to `sdb`(Which indeed was my usb drive).
Still kubuntu managed to replace `MBR` with `GRUB`on my internal drive, all files are still there and a clean install was overdue so its no that bad.
*So how do I correctly install `Kubuntu(16.04)` to an external drive to have a portable OS that can be plugged into any PC?*
Im not interested in creating a bootable `live system`. I know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I finally got it to work:

1. Create a bootable disk/usb stick with your favourite linux distro (I used [elementary os](https://elementary.io/))
2. Power of your PC and unplug it
3. Unplug all internal external hard drives from your computer (for me my `ssd` and `hdd`)
4. Plug in your bootable usb stick/insert the disk & plug in the usb device you want to install it to
5. Boot the bootable stick, choose `install 'whateverdistroyoudownloaded'`
6. Choose to manually select where to install to (For `elementary os` thats the last option - `something else`)
7. Select the usb device to install to (Should be the only device listed)
8. *Have fun with your new portable linux :)*

Instructions from: [click me](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2176132)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
stap 1: download a live cd
step 2: boot your pc from the live cd (with external HDD attached to the pc)
follow the installation like normal and when you get to select hard drive, just select your external one!

Grub however i do not know

Comment: Yes, thats what I tried and somehow it still installed parts to my internal hard drive